# PES material colorpicker library usage for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I downlaoded a libary from [ttps://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)
and having trouble to use it. I think it dose not fit with Eclipse as the usage guide from that page contain only about Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check android documentation for [Adding Library with resources using Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) this refers to Support Library but the process is quite similar for other libraries too.

IMO. It is a great chance to move to Android Studio as reference external libraries and all developer process is more easy than the one Eclipse provide!

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion. I will try to use Android Studio.